# Laravel 5 Form Model Binding Radiobutton

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, radio-button

Every user is supposed to have a role (only one). For that purpose I am using Spaties laravel-permission package.

I'm using a bunch of radio buttons in my edit and create user forms, where you are supposed to be able to select a role for the user. I got it to work with checkboxes, but at the moment you can select multiple checkboxes und thus add multiple roles to one user. Now I tried to use radiobuttons, it works, but does not pre-select the buttons.

Here is my checkbox code:

```
      @foreach ($roles as $role)
          @role('administrator')
              {!! Form::checkbox('roles[]', $role->id) !!}
              {!! Form::label($role->name, ucfirst($role->name)) !!}<br>
          @endrole
          @role('manager')
            @if(!($role->name == 'administrator'))
              {!! Form::checkbox('roles[]', $role->id) !!}
              {!! Form::label($role->name, ucfirst($role->name)) !!}<br>
            @endif
          @endrole
      @endforeach
```

And here my radio button code:

```
      @foreach ($roles as $role)
          @role('administrator')
              {!! Form::radio('roles[]', $role->id) !!}
              {!! Form::label($role->name, ucfirst($role->name)) !!}<br>
          @endrole
          @role('manager')
            @if(!($role->name == 'administrator'))
              {!! Form::radio('roles[]', $role->id) !!}
              {!! Form::label($role->name, ucfirst($role->name)) !!}<br>
            @endif
          @endrole
      @endforeach
```

Comment: To create a selected radio button. I think you need to pass in a 3rd parameter. See here https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html#checkboxes-and-radio-buttons

Comment: Yes, I know, but in my checkbox example, Laravel is doing it for me via Form Model Binding. Should be possible for radio buttons too, right?

Comment: if they can only have 1 role, why are you trying to create an array with your form input? `roles[]` is an array (many values) .. perhaps `role` would be better, a single value?

Comment: You are right, I used the array in my controller to associate users with roles, as I was able to select multiple roles before. Now I changed my controller to only take the one selected role and associate it with the user and that works. But I still can't get it to be automatically pre-selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, little update:

I used the array in my controller to associate users with roles, as I was able to select multiple roles before. Now I changed my controller to only take the one selected role and associate it with the user and that works.

Code:

```
      @foreach ($roles as $role)
          @role('administrator')
              {!! Form::radio('role', $role->id, $employee->hasRole($role)) !!}
              {!! Form::label($role->name, ucfirst($role->name)) !!}<br>
          @endrole
          @role('manager')
            @if(!($role->name == 'administrator'))
              {!! Form::radio('role', $role->id, $employee->hasRole($role)) !!}
              {!! Form::label($role->name, ucfirst($role->name)) !!}<br>
            @endif
          @endrole
      @endforeach
```

Controller:

```
      $role = $request->get('role');
      $employee->syncRoles($role);
```

That works, but isn't the whole idea of form model binding that you don't have to do it manually? If somebody could provide an answer, or a better solution, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
{!! Form::radio('role', $role->id, isset($employee) ? $employee->role_id === $role->id : false) !!}
```

If you have the user, check their role id and if its the same as the one on the loop, marked as selected

Comment: Why the downvote? This is how you, in a user form, pre-select something in a foreach

Comment: There is a syntax error in this code. Also you are creating a form "label" here not an "input" so im not sure what this will accomplish. The 3rd argument to `FormBuilder@label` is `$options = []`, an array of options (HTML attributes) for the HTML tag ...

Comment: Yeah, I know all that. I made a mistake with the function. You could've pointed that out and that's it.....

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a third parameter to the function
So try:

```
{!! Form::radio('roles[]', $role->id, TRUE) !!}
```

Or you can make an inline if statement instead if you need to calculate something first